# LINQ - Where, Group Sum

Tags: c#, sql, linq, where-clause

I have this SQL code:

```
select A.Recurso_Id, sum(case when B.cita_id is null then 0 else 1 end) as Total_Eventos, a.Recurso_Nombre, a.Recurso_Email,a.Recurso_Activo
from Agenda_Recurso a left join Agenda_Cita B
on A.Recurso_Id=B.Recurso_Id
where B.Cita_Fecha_Final > getdate()
group by A.Recurso_Id, a.Recurso_Nombre, a.Recurso_Email, a.Recurso_Activo
```

And, I need to traslate to LINQ, actually I have this code:

```
public List<Recurso> Cantidad_Eventos_Recurso(string pConexion, long pEmpresa, long pSucursal)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    List<TRegAgendaCita> _LstCitas = MetodosEnLinea.Catalogo.AgendaEvento_Lista(pConexion, pSucursal);
    List<TRegAgendaRecurso> _LstRecursos = MetodosEnLinea.Catalogo.AgendaRecurso_Lista(pConexion, pEmpresa);

    if (_LstCitas == null)
        return null;

    List<Recurso> _ListaSelect = (from Recursos in _LstRecursos
                                  join Citas in _LstCitas on Recursos.Id equals Citas.Recurso_Id  
                                  where Citas.Fecha_Final > dt
                                  into cleft
                                  select new Recurso()
                                  {
                                      Cantidad_Eventos = cleft.Where(x => x.Recurso_Id == Recursos.Id).Count(),
                                      Nombre = Recursos.Nombre,
                                      Email = Recursos.Email,
                                      Activo = Recursos.Activo,
                                      Id = Recursos.Id
                                   })
                                   .ToList();

    return _ListaSelect;
}
```

But, in the section that I want to buy the final date with today, he tells me that he is wrong, he says:A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause. Somebody could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for your query should look like this:

```
from Recursos in _LstRecursos
join Citas in _LstCitas.Where(c => c.Fecha_Final > dt) // notice the where moved here
on Recursos.Id equals Citas.Recurso_Id
into cleft
select new Recurso()
{
    Cantidad_Eventos = cleft.Where(x => x.Recurso_Id == Recursos.Id).Count(),
    Nombre = Recursos.Nombre,
    Email = Recursos.Email,
    Activo = Recursos.Activo,
    Id = Recursos.Id
}
```

You can't put an `into` clause after `where` in query syntax. If you want query syntax you can use this, which is a little more verbose:

```
from Recursos in _LstRecursos
join Citas in 
    from c in _LstCitas
    where c.Fecha_Final > dt
    select c
on Recursos.Id equals Citas.Recurso_Id
into cleft
select new Recurso()
{
    Cantidad_Eventos = cleft.Where(x => x.Recurso_Id == Recursos.Id).Count(),
    Nombre = Recursos.Nombre,
    Email = Recursos.Email,
    Activo = Recursos.Activo,
    Id = Recursos.Id
}
```